# How to add multiple listener at treeview in javafx? (hover, focused)

Tags: javafx

I have made treeview. I want to make treeview like this.

1. when I enter mouse to item, that item should change image.
2. when I clcick mouse to item, that item should chnage image.

   I know how the way getSelectionMode()... but I don't know hover event.
   Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correct.

But to change your image as soon as you click an image use a selectedItemProperty listener:

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue,
            Object newValue) {

        TreeItem<String> selectedItem = (TreeItem<String>) newValue;
        // do something
    }

});
```

<s>If you want it as soon as you hover over the item you can use a hoverProperty on the row:</s>

```
treeView.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
    final TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();

    row.hoverProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
        final YourItem yourItem = row.getItem();

        if (yourItem.isHover() ) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something
        }
    });

    return row;
});
```

(this code is from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269940/how-do-i-make-something-happen-on-hover-of-a-row-in-a-javafx-tableview))

I missread, its about a TreeView. You can try an onMouseEntered or similiar within a cellfactory:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(tv ->  {
    final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
    TreeCell<Path> cell = new TreeCell<Path>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Path item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
        }
    };

    cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        // do something
    });

    cell.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
        // do something
    });
    return cell ;
});
```

Comment: My bad, you are using a treeview and I thought its about a tree table view. See my edit.